# Wrong Number of Arguments Errors when upgrading Rails 5.2 to 6.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to upgrade an old site from Rails5.2 to 6.0 on the way to 6.1 - the recommended path.

I am getting various errors about wrong number of arguments, some of which I have managed to clear by updating or removing various gems.  Finally I'm stuck on this one:

```
.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:110:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2) (ArgumentError)
```

How do I debug this and what is the underlying problem causing all the arguments errors?

Full stack track is:

```
/Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:110:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2) (ArgumentError)
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:37:in `new'
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:37:in `build'
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:131:in `block in build'
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:127:in `each'
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:127:in `inject'
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:127:in `build'
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:512:in `block in app'
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:508:in `synchronize'
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:508:in `app'
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:97:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:363:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/will/Sites/projects/ggavatar/app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
    from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:77:in `log_to_stdout'
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:37:in `start'
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
    from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `perform'
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    from /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

## UPDATE

this blew up again shortly after the previous fix.  Same error but new stack trace.  I have a feeling it is to do with the cookies_serializer but I might be wrong.  I have set it to hybrid according to instructions in the rails guides.

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)):
  
json (1.8.6) lib/json/common.rb:155:in `initialize'
json (1.8.6) lib/json/common.rb:155:in `new'
json (1.8.6) lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
activesupport (6.0.3.5) lib/active_support/json/decoding.rb:23:in `decode'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:507:in `load'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:543:in `deserialize'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:627:in `parse'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:461:in `[]'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:114:in `get_cookie'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:89:in `block (2 levels) in unpacked_cookie_data'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:53:in `stale_session_check!'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:88:in `block in unpacked_cookie_data'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/request.rb:69:in `fetch'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/request.rb:69:in `fetch_header'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:87:in `unpacked_cookie_data'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:81:in `block in extract_session_id'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:53:in `stale_session_check!'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:80:in `extract_session_id'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:54:in `block in id'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:53:in `fetch'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:53:in `id'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:72:in `id'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:329:in `current_session_id'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:335:in `session_exists?'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:203:in `exists?'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:226:in `load_for_read!'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:92:in `[]'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/session_serializer.rb:31:in `fetch'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/proxy.rb:224:in `user'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/proxy.rb:334:in `_perform_authentication'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/proxy.rb:110:in `authenticate'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/proxy.rb:120:in `authenticate?'
devise (4.7.3) app/controllers/devise_controller.rb:109:in `require_no_authentication'
activesupport (6.0.3.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:428:in `block in make_lambda'
activesupport (6.0.3.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:181:in `block (2 levels) in halting_and_conditional'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:34:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Callbacks>'
activesupport (6.0.3.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:182:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport (6.0.3.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:513:in `block in invoke_before'
activesupport (6.0.3.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:513:in `each'
activesupport (6.0.3.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:513:in `invoke_before'
activesupport (6.0.3.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:134:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:33:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (6.0.3.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:180:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (6.0.3.5) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
activesupport (6.0.3.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:180:in `instrument'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
activerecord (6.0.3.5) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:27:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionview (6.0.3.5) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:39:in `process'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:254:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:33:in `serve'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:18:in `block in <class:Constraints>'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:48:in `serve'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:49:in `block in serve'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `each'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:834:in `call'
scout_apm (4.0.4) lib/scout_apm/instant/middleware.rb:53:in `call'
scout_apm (4.0.4) lib/scout_apm/middleware.rb:20:in `call'
bullet (6.1.4) lib/bullet/rack.rb:12:in `call'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in `context'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:648:in `call'
activerecord (6.0.3.5) lib/active_record/migration.rb:567:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.0.3.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:18:in `call'
rollbar (3.1.2) lib/rollbar/middleware/rails/rollbar.rb:25:in `block in call'
rollbar (3.1.2) lib/rollbar.rb:145:in `scoped'
rollbar (3.1.2) lib/rollbar/middleware/rails/rollbar.rb:22:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:32:in `call'
rollbar (3.1.2) lib/rollbar/middleware/rails/show_exceptions.rb:22:in `call_with_rollbar'
web-console (4.1.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:132:in `call_app'
web-console (4.1.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (4.1.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `catch'
web-console (4.1.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (6.0.3.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `call_app'
railties (6.0.3.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.0.3.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (6.0.3.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
activesupport (6.0.3.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `tagged'
railties (6.0.3.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.2) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
request_store (1.5.0) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:19:in `call'
rack-timeout (0.6.0) lib/rack/timeout/core.rb:151:in `block in call'
rack-timeout (0.6.0) lib/rack/timeout/support/timeout.rb:19:in `timeout'
rack-timeout (0.6.0) lib/rack/timeout/core.rb:150:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (6.0.3.5) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:126:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:82:in `call'
rack-mini-profiler (2.3.1) lib/mini_profiler/profiler.rb:373:in `call'
railties (6.0.3.5) lib/rails/engine.rb:527:in `call'
railties (6.0.3.5) lib/rails/railtie.rb:190:in `public_send'
railties (6.0.3.5) lib/rails/railtie.rb:190:in `method_missing'
puma (5.2.2) lib/puma/configuration.rb:248:in `call'
puma (5.2.2) lib/puma/request.rb:76:in `block in handle_request'
puma (5.2.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:337:in `with_force_shutdown'
puma (5.2.2) lib/puma/request.rb:75:in `handle_request'
puma (5.2.2) lib/puma/server.rb:431:in `process_client'
puma (5.2.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:145:in `block in spawn_thread'
source=rack-timeout id=27e40f2f-9e32-4ba3-9433-0da9a8037c07 timeout=15000ms service=407ms state=completed
```

## UPDATE 2 - switch to rails 6.1.3

stack:

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)):
  
json (1.8.6) lib/json/common.rb:155:in `initialize'
json (1.8.6) lib/json/common.rb:155:in `new'
json (1.8.6) lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
activesupport (6.1.3) lib/active_support/json/decoding.rb:23:in `decode'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:543:in `load'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:579:in `deserialize'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:668:in `parse'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:482:in `[]'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:114:in `get_cookie'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:89:in `block (2 levels) in unpacked_cookie_data'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:53:in `stale_session_check!'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:88:in `block in unpacked_cookie_data'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/request.rb:69:in `fetch'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/request.rb:69:in `fetch_header'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:87:in `unpacked_cookie_data'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:81:in `block in extract_session_id'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:53:in `stale_session_check!'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:80:in `extract_session_id'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:54:in `block in id'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:53:in `fetch'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:53:in `id'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:72:in `id'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:329:in `current_session_id'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:335:in `session_exists?'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:203:in `exists?'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:226:in `load_for_read!'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:92:in `[]'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/session_serializer.rb:31:in `fetch'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/proxy.rb:224:in `user'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/proxy.rb:334:in `_perform_authentication'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/proxy.rb:110:in `authenticate'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/proxy.rb:120:in `authenticate?'
devise (4.7.3) app/controllers/devise_controller.rb:109:in `require_no_authentication'
activesupport (6.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:427:in `block in make_lambda'
activesupport (6.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:179:in `block (2 levels) in halting_and_conditional'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:34:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Callbacks>'
activesupport (6.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:180:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport (6.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:512:in `block in invoke_before'
activesupport (6.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:512:in `each'
activesupport (6.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:512:in `invoke_before'
activesupport (6.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:115:in `block in run_callbacks'
activesupport (6.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:137:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:34:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (6.1.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:203:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (6.1.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
activesupport (6.1.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:203:in `instrument'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:33:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:249:in `process_action'
activerecord (6.1.3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:27:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:165:in `process'
actionview (6.1.3) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:39:in `process'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:254:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:33:in `serve'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:19:in `block in <class:Constraints>'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:49:in `serve'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `each'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:842:in `call'
scout_apm (4.0.4) lib/scout_apm/instant/middleware.rb:53:in `call'
scout_apm (4.0.4) lib/scout_apm/middleware.rb:20:in `call'
bullet (6.1.4) lib/bullet/rack.rb:12:in `call'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/http/permissions_policy.rb:22:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in `context'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:689:in `call'
activerecord (6.1.3) lib/active_record/migration.rb:601:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:18:in `call'
rollbar (3.1.2) lib/rollbar/middleware/rails/rollbar.rb:25:in `block in call'
rollbar (3.1.2) lib/rollbar.rb:145:in `scoped'
rollbar (3.1.2) lib/rollbar/middleware/rails/rollbar.rb:22:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:29:in `call'
rollbar (3.1.2) lib/rollbar/middleware/rails/show_exceptions.rb:22:in `call_with_rollbar'
web-console (4.1.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:132:in `call_app'
web-console (4.1.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (4.1.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `catch'
web-console (4.1.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (6.1.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `call_app'
railties (6.1.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.1.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (6.1.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:37:in `tagged'
activesupport (6.1.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `tagged'
railties (6.1.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.2) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
request_store (1.5.0) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:19:in `call'
rack-timeout (0.6.0) lib/rack/timeout/core.rb:151:in `block in call'
rack-timeout (0.6.0) lib/rack/timeout/support/timeout.rb:19:in `timeout'
rack-timeout (0.6.0) lib/rack/timeout/core.rb:150:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:26:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (6.1.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:98:in `call'
rack-mini-profiler (2.3.1) lib/mini_profiler/profiler.rb:373:in `call'
railties (6.1.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:539:in `call'
railties (6.1.3) lib/rails/railtie.rb:207:in `public_send'
railties (6.1.3) lib/rails/railtie.rb:207:in `method_missing'
puma (5.2.2) lib/puma/configuration.rb:248:in `call'
puma (5.2.2) lib/puma/request.rb:76:in `block in handle_request'
puma (5.2.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:337:in `with_force_shutdown'
puma (5.2.2) lib/puma/request.rb:75:in `handle_request'
puma (5.2.2) lib/puma/server.rb:431:in `process_client'
puma (5.2.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:145:in `block in spawn_thread'
source=rack-timeout id=ef317074-a4fb-4e9e-a6f4-cd2ddd1db3c5 timeout=15000ms service=367ms state=completed
```

Comment: Really hard to say without understanding what's causing that issue. That's just one line of a much bigger stack trace.

Comment: @tadman - fair point, i've uploaded the stacktrace

Comment: That's really strange, but you're also using 6.0.0. What about the current point-release for that, 6.0.3.5? When moving up on a Semantically Versioned dependency you should be able to go to the maximum at the same minor release without issues.

Comment: yes! that fixed it.  I guess something odd they fixed since. Cheers!

Comment: `X.0.0` releases are notoriously flaky.

Comment: it's gone wrong again

Comment: You might be battling two different classes of bugs here as Ruby 3.0 eliminated some syntax features that still worked (with warnings) in 2.7. It might be easier to bump to the latest 6.1 as that has better 3.0 support as far as I know. Fixes will (eventually) get backported to 6.0 and possibly 5.2.

Comment: Hmm, still get a long stack trace that i don't at all understand.

Comment: I'd try with Ruby 2.7 if you're getting *weird errors* to see if that resolves it. Since you're using `rbenv` that should be as easy as `rbenv local 2.7`.

Comment: @tadman - yes downgrading to 2.7 got me past this arugments issue for now. Thank you.

Comment: Downgrading to Ruby 2.7.2 fixed this for me.

Answer (score 8):

**EDIT** - Looks like you fixed it by upgrading to a newer release. I expect if you look at the changes between your versions they will have fixed the issue I've outlined below.

---

I'm assuming you upgraded to Ruby 3.0.0 at the same time as upgrading Rails. I've recently done exactly the same thing, and can with some certainty say that you're hitting an issue with changes to how keyword arguments are handled in Ruby 3.

You should read this article which explains the changes: https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/12/separation-of-positional-and-keyword-arguments-in-ruby-3-0/

Here is an example of how I had to fix this within my code.

Before Ruby 3:

```rb
  def self.fetch(*args)
    new(*args).fetch
  end

  def self.update(property, category: "default", site:, value:)
    args = [property, category: category, site: site]
    new(*args).update(value)
  end
```

After Ruby 3:

```rb
  def self.fetch(*args, **kwargs)
    new(*args, **kwargs).fetch
  end

  def self.update(property, category: "default", site:, value:)
    args = [property]
    kwargs = { category: category, site: site }
    new(*args, **kwargs).update(value)
  end
```

Comment: Thanks Jon.  This looks likely to be the problem - but it leaves me unable to debug it because the stacktrace isnt telling me (possibly because I'm not reading it correctly) where something is being called incorrectly.  My code? A Gem? Or Rails somewhere.  I've downgraded to ruby 2.7.2 with rails 6.1.3 and that has got past this arguments issue for now.  It would be nice to move to ruby 3 though.

Comment: @Will I've tracked this down to here `From: /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.8.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:102`, not sure what else to make of it at this point.

Comment: `middlewares.freeze.reverse.inject(app || block) { |a, e| e.build(a) }`

Answer (score 2):

I found a fix for this.

There's an issue with parsing JSON:
`json (1.8.6) lib/json/common.rb:155:in` parse'`

The fix for that I found here: https://github.com/flori/json/issues/399#issuecomment-734863279

It means adding a config/initializers/json.rb file to override the current parse:

```
module JSON
  module_function

  def parse(source, opts = {})
    Parser.new(source, **opts).parse
  end
end
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have any effect with Ruby 3.1.2 and rails 6.1.