# Getting "ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2))" when running rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

when trying to run `rails server` I get

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.8 application starting in development
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:111:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2) (ArgumentError)
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:37:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:37:in `build'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:101:in `block in build'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:101:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:101:in `inject'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:101:in `build'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:510:in `block in app'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:506:in `synchronize'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:506:in `app'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.2.8/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
        from C:/Users/blake/test/connectspacekids/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
        from config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
        from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.3.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.3.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.3.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.3.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.3.1/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.3.1/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.2.8/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:27:in `app'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.3.1/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.2.8/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:89:in `log_to_stdout'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.2.8/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:51:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.2.8/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
        from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.2.8/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.2.8/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.2.8/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
```

this is the first time I have tried to run this app in a bit.
Thanks!

Comment: Try solution mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66750055/wrong-number-of-arguments-errors-when-upgrading-rails-5-2-to-6-0

Answer (score 3):

Maybe your version of ruby ​​doesn't match your version of rails, it gave me a similar error. You can see version compatibility here: https://www.fastruby.io/blog/ruby/rails/versions/compatibility-table.html . If you don't want to change the code, just try the ruby ​​version corresponding to your version of rails. In your case i would try using ruby ​​version 2.7